# Why does PHP not recognize the sequence of digits from PHP_INT_MIN as an integer

Tags: php, integer

With

```
var_dump(PHP_INT_MIN);
//int(-9223372036854775808)
```

I get the number -9223372036854775808. If I assign this number to a variable, it is of the float type.

```
$n = -9223372036854775808;
var_dump($n);
//float(-9.2233720368548E+18)
```

This gives me integers:

```
$n = PHP_INT_MIN;
var_dump($n);
//int(-9223372036854775808)
```

and

```
$n = intval("-9223372036854775808");
var_dump($n);
//int(-9223372036854775808)
```

and

```
$n = sscanf("-9223372036854775808","%d")[0];
var_dump($n);
//int(-9223372036854775808)
```

Why does PHP give me a float type for -9223372036854775808 ?

Comment: It's a bug. [see here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76385)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the minus sign is not part of the syntax of a number in source code, it's the unary negation operator. So

```
$n = -9223372036854775808;
```

is treated like

```
$n = -(9223372036854775808);
```

But `9223372036854775808` is larger than `PHP_INT_MAX`, so it's parsed as a `float`, and then negated.

Comment: DOing `$n = -9223372036854775807 - 1; var_dump($n); // int(-9223372036854775808)` seems to prove this

Comment: The explanation is logical. I wouldn't have figured it out so quickly.